# How I can Unlike Comments on the Rss Feed using Graph API.?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hello Guys I am working on WPF app and I want to Unlike the Comments what I have been like so I am using like this.

> ```
>        Facebook.FacebookClient api = new FacebookClient(ExpandingNewsFeedList[0].AccessToken);
>         api.Delete(ID);
> ```

But it will give me error like this 
.(OAuthException) (#100) Can only call this method on valid test users for your app.

so how I Can overcome this problem.?

Thank you.!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To unlike, do an HTTP DELETE to the `/objectid/likes`.

Using C#, it's like this

```
facebookClient.Delete("/" + objectId + "/likes");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete content using an app except for some types of content which your App added (e.g. an app can delete its own posts)